# Bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, gnu

I've got a problem when trying to deploy by capistrano in Rails app.
Actually deploy's crashing when it's come to stage `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.
I've searched whole internet to find the answers, but there's nothing i can do with that thing.  Here are last 20 logs in capistrano.log:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

bash: line 1: 22298 Aborted                 (core dumped) /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.3 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


7fb35d476000-7fb35d477000 rw-p 00026000 fd:01 23840                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so

 DEBUG [e078da03]
7fb35d477000-7fb35d478000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 DEBUG [e078da03]
7ffc21b3f000-7ffc2233e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc223fb000-7ffc223fd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
 DEBUG [e078da03]
7ffc223fd000-7ffc223ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
 DEBUG [e078da03]       [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
 DEBUG [e078da03]

[NOTE]

 DEBUG [e078da03]

You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.

 DEBUG [e078da03]

For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

 DEBUG [e078da03]   bash: line 1: 22298 Aborted                 (core dumped) /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.3 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Maybe someone had the same problem and found the solution?

Greeting (-.-)

Edit//

I think is a problem with FFI gem. I found some solutions to this in web but it's not working for me.

```
rake stdout: /srv/http/repo-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:112: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x00007fc496276186
```

Comment: How are you running that task? Why doesn't it have the env attached? RAILS_ENV=staging ... ?

Comment: You should check log/capistrano.log for more details on the actual error and stacktrace